# Count(*) in Self Join Not working

Tags: sql

I am trying to write a query solution based on the following requirements: 
"The FinalCalledPartyNumber(voicemail 3699) is called greater than X times in a designated time frame, for example last 5 minutes."

The columns are as follows:

- ID - identity column ex. 101045
- Name - phone # calling 3699. ex. 555-123-4567 -> 3699
- FinalCalledPartyNumber - 3699
- DateTimeOrigination - datetime

Using a self join, the code below will return the result set of number of calls to 3699 and fire an alert in the phone system. I need to fire the alert only after 3699 has been call greater than X times in that 5 minute period. I tried using the Having clause with a Count(*) after the Group By. But it only works when Having Count(*) >= 1. If I change to Having Count(*) >= 2 or higher it doesn't return rows.

The syntax below in bold *Can Not* be changed, it is system generated SWQL.

```
Select VoipCallDetailsAlert.ID, VoipCallDetailsAlert.Name From VoipCallDetailsAlert
Join (
SELECT 
vcda2.Name AS vcda2_name, 
vcda2.FinalCalledPartyNumber  AS vcda2_FinalCalledPartyNumber,
vcda2.DateTimeOrigination  AS vcda2_DateTimeOrigination 
FROM VoipCallDetailsAlert  vcda2
WHERE FinalCalledPartyNumber = '3699' 
  AND vcda2.DateTimeOrigination  > DateAdd(mi, -5, GetDate())
Group By  vcda2.name, vcda2.FinalCalledPartyNumber,        vcda2.DateTimeOrigination
) Results ON vcda2_name  = VoipCallDetailsAlert.Name
```

Sample result:

```
ID          Name                    FinalCalledPartyNumber  DateTimeOrigination
101045  555-123-4567 -> 3699    3699                    12/20/15 5:29 PM
101049  555-412-4767 -> 3699    3699                    12/20/15 5:36 PM
```

Thanks, Dobber

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: By the look of it, seems to be sql server

Comment: Count() isnt working because you're grouping by the `vcda2.DateTimeOrigination` also.. which is probably unique.. Also cant really tell what part of your query cannot be changed.. can you be more specific

Comment: Using MSSQL. the part that can't change is the first line. "Select VoipCallDetailsAlert.ID, VoipCallDetailsAlert.Name From VoipCallDetailsAlert"

Comment: If I use datetimeorgination in select statement, I have to have it in the Group By, correct? otherwise syntax error.

Comment: that's true, but you don't need datetimeorgination in your select statement either if you're not using it in your JOIN afterwards or anywhere outside the sub query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    VoipCallDetailsAlert.ID, 
    VoipCallDetailsAlert.Name 
From 
    VoipCallDetailsAlert
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            *,
            COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FinalCalledPartyNumber) fcpnCount
        FROM
            VoipCallDetailsAlert
        WHERE             
            FinalCalledPartyNumber = '3699' 
            AND DateTimeOrigination > DATEADD(mi,-5,GETDATE()
    ) vcda ON VoipCallDetailsAlert.ID = vcda.ID AND fcpnCount >= 2
```

using `COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY FinalCalledPartyNumber) fcpnCount` will apply the number of times that `FinalCalledPartyNumber` was called to each record that called that number..

Comment: That worked. I had tried the Count(*) Over() last week, but wasn't aware of the Partition By piece. Read about it a few minutes ago.  This query would probably convert easily to the next question which looks to answer whether the voicemail numbers is possibly being hacked. "The FinalCalledPartyNumber(voicemail 3699) is called by the same CallingPartyNumber more than X times within a set period of time.